# In prezto how to get CTRL-RARROW working?

Tags: zsh, prezto

after installing prezto when I press CTRL - RIGHTARROW I can see these characters

```
source python;5C;5C;5C;5C
```

Whereas emacs key bindings like ALT- f work fine.
I just want my default keybindings where I can navigate using CTRL keys.

My efforts:

- Raised a issue on github + browsed other similar issues as well.
  Couldnt figure out how their solution would help my case.
- Tried setting zstyle ':prezto:module:editor' key-bindings '' but it did not
  work.
- I have also checked modeles/editor/init.zsh but the script is
  too long n I dont wanna make random changes and later keep
  maintaining those.

Can anyone suggest a way so that my keybindings remain "UNCHANGED" even after .zpreztorc is loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the prezto `editor` module, it will override your key bindings. If you have it set to emacs mode with

```bash
zstyle ':prezto:module:editor' key-bindings 'emacs'
```

you will need to add your key bindings to that named keymap. You can do that with

```bash
bindkey -M emacs '^[[1;5C' forward-word
bindkey -M emacs '^[[1;5D' backward-word
```

This will need to be run **after** the editor module is loaded. You can do that by adding it to the bottom of your `.zshrc` file. I use the `vi` keymap, so I need to add the key bindings to both the `viins` and `vicmd` keymaps.

```bash
for keymap in 'emacs' 'viins' 'vicmd'; do
    # [Ctrl-RightArrow] - move forward one word
    bindkey -M $keymap '^[[1;5C' forward-word
    # [Ctrl-LeftArrow] - move backward one word
    bindkey -M $keymap '^[[1;5D' backward-word
done

unset keymap
```